# Is it logically valid to prove existence of two objects by first proving the existence of one and then using this extant variable to prove the other?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

The other day, I tried to prove a statement that required me to show that for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$, there exists an $\eta$ and a $\gamma$ such that $\varphi(\varepsilon, \eta)$ and $\psi(\varepsilon, \gamma)$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are complicated inequalities involving $\varepsilon, \eta$ and $\varepsilon, \gamma$, respectively.

The argument I eventually made produced an $\eta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\varphi(\varepsilon, \eta)$ and $\psi(\varepsilon, \gamma)$ were both satisfied...**however**, the $\gamma$ that I constructed depended upon the value of $\eta$. This struck me as a possible issue because it seems to me that I imposed an *order* on how to determine the necessary $\gamma$ and $\eta$ for a given $\varepsilon$. Specifically, my $\eta$ is only a function of $\varepsilon$. But my $\gamma$ is a function of $\varepsilon$ **and** $\eta$. Therefore, for a given $\varepsilon$, I cannot construct my $\gamma$ until I have first constructed my $\eta$.

Is this an issue? Or is the proof nonetheless valid?

Comment: It's not an issue. Once you have proved one object exists satisfying properties, you may then use that object, and the fact that it satisfies that object, in later proofs. There's actually a word for this procedure in logic, it's called [existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation).

Comment: @LeeMosher perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'order' that you refer to is a feature of your *proof*: you first prove the existence one thing, and then, on the basis of that, prove the existence of a second thing.

But this order is not a feature of the very existence of those very objects.

In sum, don't confuse the nature of the proof you use to prove something about some world with the nature of that world itself.

Comment: I like that final sentence. Thank you for the input. As an FYI, here is the proof that this post refers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464202/if-lim-x-to-afx-m-and-lim-x-to-agx-n-then-lim-x-to-af-cdo