# If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=M$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=N$, then $\lim_{x \to a}(f\cdot g)(x)=MN$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

In the below section, I will prove the following statement:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=M$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}g(x)=N$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}(f\cdot g)(x)=MN$

There are more standard variations, but I would like to know if the following argument is valid, as I find it more intuitive than some of the more pedagogical approaches.

We will make use of this general lemma, which is straightforward to prove:

> If $|a| \lt \varepsilon$, then for any $M \in \mathbb R$: $|Ma| \lt |M\varepsilon|$

---

For an $\varepsilon \gt 0$, we want to show that there is a $\delta_\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that for any $x \in (a-\delta_\varepsilon,a+\delta_\varepsilon)\setminus\{a\}$, we have: $MN-\varepsilon \lt f(x)g(x)\lt MN+\varepsilon \quad(*_1)$.

For any $x$, we must have that there are $y$ and $z$ such that $f(x)+y=M$ and $g(x)+z=N$. Therefore, $MN$ can be written as: $MN=f(x)g(x)+f(x)z+g(x)y+yz$. Solving for $f(x)g(x)$, we have that:

\begin{align}f(x)g(x)=MN-f(x)z-g(x)y-yz\end{align}

Rewriting $(*_1)$ with this, we now have:

\begin{align}&MN-\varepsilon \lt MN -f(x)z-g(x)y-yz \lt MN+\varepsilon \\& \end{align}

Because $y=M-f(x)$ and $z=N-g(x)$, we can simplify:

$$-\varepsilon \lt f(x)z+g(x)y+yz \lt \varepsilon \implies-\varepsilon \lt f(x)(N-g(x))+g(x)(M-f(x)))+(M-f(x))\cdot(N-g(x)) \lt \varepsilon$$

Factoring out $N-f(x)$ gives us:

$$-\varepsilon \lt M(N-g(x))+g(x)(M-f(x)) \lt \varepsilon$$

This form is particularly useful because by assumption, for any $\gamma \gt 0, \eta \gt 0$ there are a $\delta_\gamma \gt 0$ and $\delta_\eta \gt 0$, respectively, such that:

1. $\forall x \in(a-\delta_\gamma, a+\delta_\gamma)\setminus\{a\}: -\gamma \lt N-g(x)\lt \gamma$
2. $\forall x \in(a-\delta_\eta, a+\delta_\eta)\setminus\{a\}:-\eta \lt M-f(x) \lt \eta$

Applying our lemma, we have that:

$-|g(x) \eta| \lt g(x) \cdot (M-f(x)) \lt |g(x) \eta|$ and $-|M\gamma| \lt M
\cdot(N-g(x))\lt |M\gamma|$. Adding these two inequalities together gives us:

$$-|M\gamma| - |g(x) \eta| \lt M(N-g(x))+g(x)\cdot(M-f(x)) \lt |M\gamma|+|g(x)\eta|$$

Note that because $N-\gamma \lt g(x) \lt N+\gamma$, it must be the case that $0\leq |g(x)| \lt \max\left(|N-\gamma|,|N+\gamma| \right)=\alpha$. We can then rewrite our above inequality as:

$$-|M\gamma|-|\alpha \eta| \lt M(N-g(x))+g(x)\cdot(M-f(x))\lt |M\gamma|+|\alpha \eta| \quad (*_2)$$

To conclude this proof, we need only solve for $\gamma$ and $\eta$ such that:

$$-\varepsilon \leq -|M\gamma|-|\alpha \eta| \quad \text{AND} \quad |M\gamma|+|\alpha \eta|\leq \varepsilon$$

Suppose we let $\gamma \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2|M|}$. Then we can let $\eta \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2\alpha}$. Under these conditions, we have that $-|M\gamma|-|\alpha \eta|=-\varepsilon$ and $|M\gamma|+|\alpha \eta|=\varepsilon$.

By $(*_2)$, we can then let $\delta_\varepsilon=\min\left(\delta_\gamma,\delta_\eta\right)$, which will allow us to conclude $(*_1)$.

Comment: How is this different from the standard approach?

Comment: The lines in the middle involving $MN\pm\varepsilon$ are scratch work and aren't really part of the proof.  You should skip to the part below this section and then, at the end, end up with the desired inequalities.

Comment: Please explain the computation involving $\Rightarrow$, it's not clear how that line follows.

Comment: This response is somewhat off-point, so I am commenting, rather than answering.  In my opinion, your entire approach, while (presumably) valid, is not recommended.  A much simpler approach is (assuming that $0 < M,N$):  $$M - \epsilon_1 < f(x) < M + \epsilon_1 ~~~~\text{and}~~~~ N - \epsilon_2 < g(x) < N + \epsilon_2 \implies $$
$$MN - \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1\epsilon_2 < f(x)g(x) < MN + \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1\epsilon_2.$$  So, choose $\epsilon_1 = \min[1/2,\epsilon_3/3], ~~\epsilon_2 = [\epsilon_3/3].$

Comment: Re last comment, once you accept the proof as complete in the specific case of $0 < M,N$ you can consider what happens (for example) if $M < 0$.  Then, you can define $f_1(x) = - f(x) \implies \lim_{x \to a} f_1(x) = -M > 0.$  So, you don't have to go through the whole rigmarole more than once.

Comment: @MichaelBurr for proofs like this, I try to include the 'scratch work' so that one can see how all aspects of the proof are derived. I added some additional comments for the $\implies$ section. As to your first comment, my book works from an unexplained lemma of: "If $|x-x_0|\lt \min\left(1,\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)}\right)$ and $|y-y_0|\lt\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$, then $|xy-x_0y_0| \lt \varepsilon$". Given my book's status (author is Spivak), I assumed this was the standard treatment.

Comment: In your final proof, you should not include scratch work - it can be confusing because it is not logically sound (it usually has assumptions that don't come from the previous steps).  If you want to include your scratch work, it should be separate from the main proof and clearly labeled as scratch work.